# Data in Facebook?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just want to know if I use facebook api on my application for modules just as comments, events and pages.

Will the data be stored in facebook or it will be stored in my db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the API, it will be stored on facebook. Then you can decide whether to store it in your database as well.